# Sorting Embedded Document lists in Mongoengine by two different fields

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine

I have the following model in Mongoengine:

```
class Post(EmbeddedDocument):
     date_created = DateTimeField()
     date_updated = DateTimeField()
     text = StringField()

class User(Document):
     name = StringField()
     posts = SortedListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Post), ordering = 'date_created')
```

I want to be able to alternately retrieve for a user their most recent post by `date_created` and `date_updated`. I can use the `ordering` parameter in a `SortedListField` to order by `date_created` - what can I do to query the posts so that the most recent post is returned to me in terms of `date_updated`?